# Missing Modules while trying to deploy rails app on elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install ruby on rails app via elastic beanstalk that uses node and npm.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-201 client]$ node -v
v7.8.0
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-201 client]$ npm -v
4.2.0
```

The problem is I am getting following error at the `"rake assets:precompile"` step

```
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
  cd client && npm run build:client

  > @ build:client /var/app/ondeck/client
  > npm run ensure-node-version && webpack --config webpack.client.config.js


  > @ ensure-node-version /var/app/ondeck/client
  > check-node-version --package

  sh: check-node-version: command not found

  npm ERR! Linux 4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v7.8.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "ensure-node-version"
  npm ERR! node v7.8.0
  npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
  npm ERR! file sh
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
  npm ERR! syscall spawn
  npm ERR! @ ensure-node-version: `check-node-version --package`
  npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the @ ensure-node-version script 'check-node-version --package'.
  npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
  npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     check-node-version --package
  npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  npm ERR!     npm bugs
  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
  npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     /home/webapp/.npm/_logs/2019-01-26T17_19_36_394Z-debug.log
```

But i can see chceck-node-version is installed

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-201 client]$ npm view check-node-version version
3.2.0
```

Interestingly i get missing script check-node-version when i run following command

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-201 client]$ npm run check-node-version
npm ERR! Linux 4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v7.8.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "check-node-version"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! missing script: check-node-version
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2019-01-26T17_38_37_148Z-debug.log
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if run it under webapp user? npm view check-node-version version

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-90 ~]$ npm view check-node-version version
3.2.0

Comment: i meant node/npm/modules are installed for webapp user, but you trying to run it under ec2-user

Comment: -bash-4.2$ whoami
webapp
-bash-4.2$ npm view check-node-version version
3.2.0

Comment: ok, list all node versions. ls -la /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/ . check where npm runs, execute command: which npm

Comment: `-bash-4.2$ ls -la /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 Jan 27 11:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     4096 Jan 12 07:41 ..
drwxrwxr-x 7 ssm-user ssm-user 4096 Jan 27 11:49 node-v7.8.0-linux-x64
-bash-4.2$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
-bash-4.2$ ls -l /usr/bin/npm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 72 Jan 27 11:49 /usr/bin/npm -> /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v7.8.0-linux-x64/bin/npm
-bash-4.2$`

Comment: /usr/bin/npm is it symlink? if yes, then where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187388/discussion-between-neverbe-and-sjm).